# nvarchar(), MD5, and matching data in Bigquery

Tags: t-sql, google-bigquery, azure-sql-database

I am consolidating a couple of datasets in BQ, and in order to do that i need to run MD5 on some data.

The problem I'm having is a chunk of the data is coming MD5'ed already from Azure, and the original field is nvarchar()

I'm not as familiar with Azure, but what I find is that:

`HASHBYTES('MD5',CAST('6168a1f5-6d4c-40a6-a5a4-3521ba7b97f5' as nvarchar(max)))`
returns
`0xCD571D6ADB918DC1AD009FFC3786C3BC` (which  is expected value)

where

`HASHBYTES('MD5','6168a1f5-6d4c-40a6-a5a4-3521ba7b97f5')`
returns
`0x94B04255CD3F8FEC2B3058385F96822A` which is equivalent to what i get if i run

`MD5(TO_HEX(MD5('6168a1f5-6d4c-40a6-a5a4-3521ba7b97f5')))` in Bigquery, but it is unfortunately *not* what i need to match to, i need to match to the `nvarchar` version in BQ but i cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem, posting here for posterity.

The field in Azure is being stored as a nvarchar(50) which is encoded as UTF-16LE